# multiple toggle for different elements add remove class

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, toggleclass

Her is my function. there only think its not working is when i click .close-hideme i want to remove class noactive and add class active

```
$(function () {    
    var text = $(this).text();   
    $(".hideme").hide();    
    var elements = $(".bold_blue, .bold_blue_img");    
    elements.click(function () {   
            var element = $(this);   
            elements.removeClass("active");   
            if (text == 'dot' || text == '+' && !$(".hideme").is(":visible")) {   
                    $(this).closest('tr').find(".bold_blue_img").text($(this).closest('tr').find(".bold_blue_img").text() == '-' ? '+' : '-');    
                    $(this).closest('tr').find(".bold_blue_img").removeClass("active").addClass("noactive");
                    return false;   
            }    
            else {    
                    $(this).parents("tr").next().slideToggle("slow");    
                    $(this).closest('tr').find(".bold_blue_img").text($(this).closest('tr').find(".bold_blue_img").text() == '-' ? '+' : '-');   
                    $(this).closest('tr').find(".bold_blue_img").toggleClass('noactive');     
                    return false;   
            }   
    });   
    $('.close-hideme').bind('click', function () {    
            if (!$(".hideme").is(":visible")) {   
                    $(this).closest('tr').find(".bold_blue_img").removeClass("noactive").addClass("active");    
                    $(this).parents(".hideme").hide("slow");   
                    return false;    
            }   
    });       
});
```

any one have idea how to change that class to active, here html code

```
<table style="width:100%">   
 <tbody>   
<tr class="parent">   
  <td><a class="bold_blue">dot</a><a class="bold_blue_img active">+</a>   
  <!-- i've to use 2 different hrefs here plus is text only but inside css there is class active and noactive with background images -->   
  </td>   
</tr>   
<tr class="hideme">   
  <td><a class="close-hideme right">X</a>
  <!-- this button is not working, i mean is hiding but is not changing bold_blue_img class to active -->
 </td>   
  </tr>   
</tbody>   
 </table>
```

Comment: it would be easier to help if you could provide a fiddle so we can also get a look at your html

Comment: Is it `.hide` or `.hideme`?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without HTML, but try this (`closest()` instead of `parent()`).

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(".bold_blue_img").removeClass("noactive").addClass("active");
```

Comment: .hideme sorry i didn't spotted that
closest for some reason in not working as well